# Importing bookmarks from internet explorer to Firefox 3.5

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, bookmarks, import

This is a silly question, but the first Google result speaks of a 'bookmark manager' with an option to import favorites from IE, but I can only find 'organize bookmarks' with an option to import from HTML, and in IE I can't find where to export to HTML. Can anyone help?

Comment: What version if IE? In IE 7 I click the "Add to Favorites" button (obviously misnamed) and there's an "Import and Export..." option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just click on "Import HTML", the first screen of the "wizard" will let you choose between import from an HTML file, or straight from Internet Explorer:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Bookmarks -> Organize Bookmarks -> Import and Backup -> Import HTML -> Microsoft Internet Explorer

it will take them from IE for you.